# WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I use this code and it generates error about shape.

```
def train_val_generators(training_images, training_labels, validation_images, validation_labels):
  
  training_images = np.expand_dims(training_images,axis=3)
  validation_images = np.expand_dims(validation_images,axis=3)

  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                     rotation_range= 40,
                                     width_shift_range=0.2,
                                     height_shift_range=0.2,
                                     shear_range=0.2,
                                     zoom_range=0.2,
                                     horizontal_flip=True,
                                     fill_mode='nearest')


  train_generator = train_datagen.flow(x=training_images,
                                       y=training_labels,
                                       batch_size=32) 

  validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

  validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow(x=validation_images,
                                                 y=validation_labels,
                                                 batch_size=32) 

  return train_generator, validation_generator

train_generator, validation_generator = train_val_generators(training_images, training_labels, validation_images, validation_labels)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(26, activation='softmax')
])
  

  model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop',
                loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(train_generator, #this line generates error
                    epochs=15,
                    validation_data=validation_generator)
```

Here is the error i get:

ValueError: in user code:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 26) are incompatible
```

I have tried to change my code according to advice from similar problems on Stack Overflow, but none of it has helped me. For example, this: [Warning about shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73277459/warningtensorflowmodel-was-constructed-with-shape-none-66-200-3)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely related to the labels. what is the shape of your training_labels?

Comment: make sure your training labels are similar to the shape of your output layer.

Comment: Sorry, I am new at this could you explain a bit more what you mean shape of output layer. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Looking at your model, you are trying to train a classification model. The output layer is basically the last layer of your model or this line<tf.keras.layers.Dense(26, activation='softmax')>. This line of code means your output layer has the shape of (None, 26) and activation of softmax. So, your classification label has to match this shape.

Comment: From your error message,  it is telling you that your classification label (training_labels and validation_labels) is the shape of (None, 1). So, this shape has to be  (None, 26). You either need to change the shape of your output layer or input layer depending on input shape. If you could give more detail about your training data, it would be helpful.

Comment: My training data is open library sign_mnist where you have 28x28 black and white pictures of 26 letters of English alphabet. First element of list is label and others represent pixels of picture.

Comment: I see. you need to encode the label to fit to the model. you can use for instance one-hot encoding of size 26. Then you would have the shape that matches your output layer.

Comment: you can use LabelBinarizer to do so.

label_binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
training_label = label_binarizer.fit_transform(training_labels)

Comment: Actually the solution was to use other loss function sparce_categorical_crossentropy because categorical_crossentropy only works with one_hot encoding and my labels are integers, but anyway thanks a lot